# Re-order R data frame columns by date

Tags: r

I am trying to output several basic tables and have the columns consistently ordered by Month-Year. Before, this didn't seem to be an issue, but now I am getting the columns in an incorrect order--appear to be alphabetical by year.

```
f$admission int [1:323] 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
f$date  chr [1:323] "Jan-14" "Jan-14" "Jan-14" "Jan-14" "Jan-14" "Jan-14" "Jan-14" "Jan-14" "Jan-14" ...
```

Here is my code for creating the table

```
  ## Create Monthly variable based on Admission Date
    f$date <- format(as.Date(f$DateOriginal), "%b-%y")
    f$date <- f[order(f$date),]
    table(f$admission, order(as.date(f$date)))
```

And here is my output:

```
Apr-14 Aug-14 Dec-14 Feb-14 Feb-15 Jan-14 Jan-15 Jul-14 Jun-14 Mar-14 May-14 Nov-14 Oct-14 Sep-14
  1     18     15     19     12      9     14     18     14     13     16     21     20     17     18
  2      8      5      5      0      1      5      2      1      3      8      6      9      5     10
  3      1      2      1      2      1      1      0      2      4      0      1      2      1      1
  4      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      1      1
  5      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      1
  6      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
  7      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  9      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
table(f$admission, factor(f$date, levels=unique(f$date)))
```

#### data

```
date <-  paste(rep(rep(month.abb,each=2),2), rep(c(14,15),each=24), sep="-")
 set.seed(24)
 f <- data.frame(admission=sample(1:5, 24, replace=TRUE), 
                          date, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```